# How can I prevent recompiling when switching between ghci and ghc

Tags: haskell, emacs, ghc, ghci

When I use both ghci with `-fobject-code` and command-line ghc, code is compiled fully when switching from one to the other. For example, when I work interactively in Emacs using haskell inferior mode configured to use `cabal repl`, code loads and compiles fine. Then I do a `cabal build` and same code is recompiled.

How can I prevent this double compilation assuming `-fobject-code` in ghci actually uses the same kind of binary format than ghc does?

Comment: I don't know about ghc-mod, but GHC defaults to storing compiles code next to source code, whereas Cabal puts the compiled code in the distribution folder...

Comment: Actually, I talk about ghc-mod but I was wrong: I am using haskell-mode with embedded REPL which uses `cabal repl` under the hood.

Comment: @insitu, please edit the correction into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have `ghci` and friends use different suffixes for the compiled files. Add the following to your `~/.ghci`:

```
:set -hisuf i_hi
:set -osuf i_o
```

...and ghci will output stuff to `foo.i_hi` and `foo.i_o` which won't overwrite the `.hi` and `.o` files of ghc.

Answer (score 2):

One workaround to this issue (seven years late, sorry! I'm putting it here in case someone finds it by Google) is the following:

Don't use `-fobject-code` in your GHCi flags, and instead specify `-osuf dyn_o -hisuf dyn_hi`. Doing this will get GHCi to opportunistically load object code built with `-dynamic-too` when available, and otherwise interpret the code.

Practically: `cabal repl lib:sample --ghc-options "-osuf dyn_o -hisuf dyn_hi"`.

See the GHC bug "ghci no longer loads dynamic .o files" for more details: https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/13604